How to launch and terminate foreground service correctly in Android
I developed an Android app in kotlin which should launch a Maplestory game server service on foreground when clicking Start button and stop the service when clicking Stop button.
Sometimes Application will throw "Service not registered" or "leaked ServiceConnection" error after step 3:

Click the start button to launch the service.
Minimize the app and back to desktop.
Re-enter the app and click the stop button.

So I'm confused what's the right approach to launch and terminate the service ?
Method when clicking buttons:
https://github.com/speedyHKjournalist/MapleServerAndroid/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/mapleserver/MainCompose.kt#L238
Service definition:
https://github.com/speedyHKjournalist/MapleServerAndroid/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/mapleserver/ServerService.kt
fun doBindService(
    context: Context,
    connection: ServiceConnection,
    serviceIntent: Intent
) {
    context.bindService(serviceIntent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
}

fun startMapleServer(context: Context, serviceIntent : Intent) {
    startForegroundService(context, serviceIntent)
}


fun stopMapleServer(context: Context, serviceIntent : Intent, connection : ServiceConnection) {
    context.unbindService(connection)
    context.stopService(serviceIntent)
}

Activity com.mapleserver.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection MainComposeKt$MainCompose$mConnection$1@70de9fd that was originally bound here
android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Activity com.mapleserver.MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection MainComposeKt$MainCompose$mConnection$1@70de9fd that was originally bound here
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1953)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcherCommon(LoadedApk.java:1825)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1804)
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1976)
at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1907)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:822)
at MainComposeKt.doBindService(MainCompose.kt:243)
at MainComposeKt.MainCompose(MainCompose.kt:80)
at com.mapleserver.MainActivity$onCreate$1$1$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:36)
at com.mapleserver.MainActivity$onCreate$1$1$1$1.invoke(MainActivity.kt:35)

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.mapleserver, PID: 28471
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: MainComposeKt$MainCompose$mConnection$1@3da8285
at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1899)
at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:2031)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:858)
at MainComposeKt.stopMapleServer(MainCompose.kt:251)
at MainComposeKt$MainCompose$2$2$1$1$1$2.invoke(MainCompose.kt:140)
at MainComposeKt$MainCompose$2$2$1$1$1$2.invoke(MainCompose.kt:136)
at com.mapleserver.ui.theme.StopButtonKt$StopButton$1$1.invoke(StopButton.kt:20)
at com.mapleserver.ui.theme.StopButtonKt$StopButton$1$1.invoke(StopButton.kt:19)


Does this answer your question? Activity  has leaked ServiceConnection @438030a8 that was originally bound here

I first bind the service in main compose then use startonforeground to start, does the sequence matter ?

Your foreground service for the Maplestory game server might have registration or binding issues. Ensure your service is declared correctly in the manifest and use bindService with proper unbinding to connect to the service from your activity. Remember to show a notification when the service runs in the foreground. Also consider foregroundServiceType in AndroidManifest.xml.

I've already declared the service in AndroidManifest.xml:
    <service
            android:name=".ServerService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="specialUse"
            android:exported="false"
    />


https://github.com/speedyHKjournalist/MapleServerAndroid/commit/fb3a1c1aa01a3910818ac94db8e08182dfcfee8c
Need to use Flow to pass service status from Broadcast receiver to MainCompose, we shouldn't bind service, register broadcast receiver in Composable because Composable will be called every time when we enter it, instead it should handle UI related stuff only.
